# Guardar array en BD con laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, array

Tengo un create para el registro de usuarios donde hay un MULTIPLE SELECT para asignarle varios entes al usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me lanza un array por cada opción que marco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi tengo el multiple select:

```
<label for="entity_id">Asignar Entes</label>
  <select id="ms" name="entity_id[]" multiple="multiple">
     @foreach($entities as $e)  
       <option value="{{$e->id}}">{{$e->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```

Y el controlador para guardar los datos del usuario:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user= new \App\User();
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->entity_id=$request->entity_id;
    $user->role_id=$request->role_id;
    $user->password=bcrypt($request->password);

    if($user->save()){

     return redirect()->route('users.index', $user->id)
         ->with('info', 'Usuario guardado con éxito');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('users.index')
         ->with('info', 'No se guardó el usuario');
    }
}
```

Y los campos de la base de datos, donde entity_id es el campo que quiero guardar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como guardo ese array en mi base de datos? gracias de antemano.

Comment: necesitas otra tabla que contenga asignar entes y el user_id; por cada asignar entes que el usuario tenga se creara un registro, y lo consultas con el id del usuario

Comment: exactamente necesitas otra tabla Pivot